# Google map circles are not round

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to draw many circles over a Google Map (many circles per rooftop).

I tried the Circle class and seem to be okay for big circles, but when drawing small ones they are not round at all.

The code I'm using goes like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < latitudes.length; i++)
    var newCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        map: map,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes[i], longitudes[i]),
        radius: 0.5
    });
    newCircle.setMap(map);
```

And the result is: [image: google map with white circles]

I know that there are other ways to draw points over a google map, but I'd really like to go with the google solution if there is a way to make them look round as they should be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use Symbols, they should be perfect circles. Try this:

```
var whiteCircle = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillOpacity: 1.0,
    fillColor: "white",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeColor: "white",
    strokeWeight: 1.0,
    scale: 1.0
};
```

Then

```
for(var i = 0; i < latitudes.length; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes[i], longitudes[i])
    var newCircle = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: whiteCircle,
        position: latLng
    });
    newCircle.setMap(map);
}
```

The circles are likely to be huge, so play around with the scale to get it right.

I have never used the Circle class. Symbols were introduced in this year's Google I/O. They are vectors, meaning you can pretty much define your own shape. Here's a link for more info:
[**googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/06/powerful-data-visualization-with.html**](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/06/powerful-data-visualization-with.html)

Comment: Thanks, it does the job. However, they are not very efficient performance-wise (google.maps.Circle in't either though)

Comment: I wouldn't know performance-wise. I only recently switched to vectors instead of images. Editing them is much easier than having to switch markers. I don't draw a lot of the images, but from my experience with Gmaps, too many markers slow it down (except for back in the Flash map days)

Comment: I finally went with custom makers, using different png's for circle colors, and scaling with the size property

Comment: Anyone any an example showing how you might draw a circle symbol but keep it's size fixed? It seems they scale automatically, I want a circle to always cover the same area.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the scale of the symbol is relative to the viewport and not the distance-scales on the map.

Comment: How could you use this solution but giving the circle symbol a specific radius in meters?

Answer (score -2):

Anti-aliasing is critical.

`g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)`

The Google solution will not work for smaller circles.

Comment: I'm sorry but what is `g2d`?

Comment: @Nicolas seems to be [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html)